# A callback method to execute post JSON to object conversion in Jersey JAX RS

Tags: json, validation, callback, jackson, jersey

I am using Jersey rest services with Jackson API for conversion of `JSON` String to `POJO`s. All the member variables of the `POJO` class need to be validated. I already have a framework in place for validation.

What I want to know is if there is any callback method or mechanism which can call my validation API post the `JSON` to `POJO` conversion itself. Doing this would make my job easier as I will not have to call the API at all the places in my Rest service class.

```
public class MyPojoClass{

   private int interestRateCode;
   private String name;

   //just edited
   private List<TestDTO> testObjs;

   //Psuedo code
   //@PostDeserialization
   public String callbackMethod(Object obj){

       if(!ValidationAPI.validate(obj))
                return "false";
   }

}
```

The TestDTO:

```
public class TestDTO {

    private int var1;
    private String stringVar;

    public TestDTO() {
       System.out.println("This constructor does get called every time");
    }
}
```

Is there any annotation like PostDeserialization to achieve this. This will help me to make every `POJO` class having only one callback method for validation.

The JSON I am passing is

```
{"interestRateCode": 101,"name": "T", 
                                 "testObjs": [
                                    {"var1" :10, "stringVar": "Arunabh"},
                                    {"var1" :15, "stringVar": "Hejib"}
                                ]}
```

Anyone who can help me on this problem? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use a [Request Filter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). In the filter you would:

1. Get the resource `Method` using the injected `ResourceInfo`
2. Get the entity class by traversing the `Method` `Parameter`s and checking for the method parameter without any annotations. Unless you're using [bean validation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) where `@Valid` is used next to the parameter, then the entity parameter always is the parameter with no annotations. This is how we determine the entity parameter. From the parameter, we get the class.
3. Get the entity objects from the request.
4. From the entity class, using from reflection, find the `Method` with the `@PostDeserialization` annotation.
5. Call the method using reflection.

Below is a complete test. The `ValidationFilter` is the class with previous mentioned steps.

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * Run like any other JUnit test. A couple required dependencies.
 *
 *  <dependency>
 *    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
 *    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 *    <scope>test</scope>
 *  </dependency>
 *  <dependency>
 *    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 *    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
 *    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 *  </dependency>
 */
public class PostDeserializationTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface PostDeserialization {}


    public static class ValidationError extends RuntimeException {
        public ValidationError(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }


    public static class ValidationErrorMapper
            implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationError> {

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(ValidationError ex) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .entity(ex.getMessage())
                    .build();
        }
    }


    public static class Bean {
        public String value;

        @PostDeserialization
        public void validate() {
            if (!"expected".equals(value)) {
                throw new ValidationError("value must be 'expected'");
            }
        }
    }


    public static class ValidationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        @Context
        private ResourceInfo info;

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
            Class<?> entityClass = getEntityClass();
            if (entityClass != null) {
                final ContainerRequest cr = (ContainerRequest) request;
                cr.bufferEntity();
                final Object entity = cr.readEntity(entityClass);

                findMethodAndValidate(entity);
            }
        }

        private Class<?> getEntityClass() {
            final Method rm = info.getResourceMethod();
            final Annotation[][] paramAnnotations = rm.getParameterAnnotations();
            for (int i = 0; i < paramAnnotations.length; i++) {
                // entity parameters have no annotations.
                if (paramAnnotations[i].length == 0) {
                    return rm.getParameterTypes()[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void findMethodAndValidate(Object entity) {
            final Method[] methods = entity.getClass().getMethods();
            for (Method method: methods) {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PostDeserialization.class)) {
                    // validation method should take no parameters.
                    if (method.getParameterCount() != 0) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(
                                "Validation method must not have parameters.");
                    }
                    try {
                        method.invoke(entity);
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                        // if an exception happens during invocation,
                        // an InvocationException is thrown. We want the cause,
                        // expecting it to be a ValidationError.
                        Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
                        if (cause instanceof ValidationError) {
                            throw (ValidationError) cause;
                        } else {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(
                                "Error calling validation method.", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @POST
        @Consumes("application/json")
        public String post(Bean bean) {
            return bean.value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .register(TestResource.class)
                .register(ValidationErrorMapper.class)
                .register(ValidationFilter.class)
                .register(new ExceptionMapper<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        return Response.serverError()
                                .entity(t.getMessage()).build();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidationError() {
        final Bean bean = new Bean();
        bean.value = "not expected";
        final Response response = target("test")
                .request()
                .post(Entity.json(bean));

        assertEquals(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("value must be 'expected'", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNoValidationError() {
        final Bean bean = new Bean();
        bean.value = "expected";
        final Response response = target("test")
                .request()
                .post(Entity.json(bean));

        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("expected", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try implementing this.

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameters() inside getEntityClass() method. Any idea what could be the reason for this. I am using Java7.

Comment: I used Java8 to get rid of this error. Not sure if my product allows Java 8 usage so can you tell me how to make it work with Java7. Also, the execution stops at this line final Object entity = cr.readEntity(entityClass); Looks like this line has a problem but I dont see anything in stack trace.

Comment: I updated the code for `getEntityClass` for Java7. As far as your other problem, I can't reproduce the problem. Not even sure I understand what you mean by "execution stops". The code I posted above works fine. If you can update my code to reproduce your problem, I can have a look at it. Preferable just give me a link to a Gist that I can just copy/paste/run (just like my code I posted above).

Comment: I figured out the issue with readEntity. I have one more question if you can help. What if MyPojoClass contains a List<TestDTO> kind of field. I want to put similar validate method within TestDTO also. Is it possible to get the validate method executed for all such List of objects within MyPojoClass.

Comment: I have edited the code snippet with TestDTO requirement.

Comment: That's up to your validation framework that you supposedly have. Has nothing to do with me.

Comment: But the validate method of TestDTO doesnt get called.

Comment: And that's part of your framework. You wanted to know how to get a method called. I answered that. It's your job to figure out what that method does, not mine,

Comment: Okay. I will write the code required to validate TestDTO inside the callback() of MyPojoClass. Thanks a lot for your help. :)